# How to prevent double uri encoding

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml

I want to show a photo through a firestore URI in QT5. I can set the image path but QT5 encodes the URI and converts %2F to '/' which leads to an incorrect firestore-URI.

The project is written for python3 and pyqt5. I've tried already to use a QUrl object with its functions to convert it to .url(), .toString(), .toDisplayString().

With

```py
urllib.request.urlretrieve(uri, path)
```

I'm able to download the photo, but I want to show it directly from the firestore path without saving it to disk.

QML

```
Row {
   anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
   height: 128
   spacing: 16
   Image {
      source: root.image
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
   }
}
```

Python

```py
url = QtCore.QUrl(user['photo']).toDisplayString()
print("user url: ", user['photo'])
print("QUrl: ", url)
messagebox.setProperty('image', user['photo'])
```

Result

```
user url:  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projectx-835b4.appspot.com/o/users%2FNTb2Wz2%2Fprofilepicture%2F1234.jpg?alt=media&token=3d3b25c4-78e1-48a9-a311
QUrl:  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projectx-835b4.appspot.com/o/users%2FNTb2Wz2%2Fprofilepicture%2F1234.jpg?alt=media&token=3d3b25c4-78e1-48a9-a311
file:///home/tux/projectsx/content/ThankYouView.qml:112:21: QML Image: Error transferring https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projectx-835b4.appspot.com/o/users/NTb2Wz2/profilepicture/1234.jpg?alt=media&token=3d3b25c4-78e1-48a9-a311 - server replied: Bad Request
```

Comment: post an answer instead of pointing in a comment.

Comment: Hey Daniel. It's great to hear that you found a solution to your problem. As @eyllanesc said, can you post the solution as an answer instead of in your question? Self-answering is encouraged on Stack Overflow, and is a great way to both help others, and gain reputation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you, next time I will do. This was my first post on Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: @Daniel You can do it **now**
 so you will help other members of the community

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by changing the property type from string to url

```
...
Item {
    id: root
    property url image
    ...
}
...
```